# #!unspecific error while printing values in Scheme

Tags: scheme, lisp, racket, mit-scheme

I keep getting my output as :

```
Exam Avg: 50.#!unspecific
```

Whenever I try to print my program in scheme. I am using two functions print and secprint where I think the error might be happening:

```
(define (print cnt List)
    (if (= cnt 1) (printEmp (car List))
        (secprint cnt List )))

(define (secprint cnt List)
    (printEmp (car List))
    (newline)
    (print (- cnt 1) (cdr List)))

Could someone please help with this? I am new to scheme and can't seem to figure out where I am going wrong.

Edit: Other code that might be useful.


(define (avg List)
  (cond ((string=? "std" (car (split List)))
  (display (/ (examTotals List) 3.0)))
  (else 0))
)
```

Comment: What's `avg` and `avg2`?

Comment: Almost certainly `#!unspecific` is the way the unspecified return value of something is being printed.  I am not sure why it's not on a line on its own, as I'd expect it to be the return value of `newline`.

Comment: @molbdnilo avg and avg2 are the functions I'm using to get the exam grade, I can edit the original to include them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `display` procedure writes to output, and then returns an unspecified value. You use `display` for its side-effect of printing data, not for its return value.

```
(define (avg List)
  (cond ((string=? "std" (car (split List)))
         (display (/ (examTotals List) 3.0)))
        (else 0)))
```

The `avg` procedure returns the value of the last expression evaluated; when the `display` branch evaluates, the unspecified value is returned to the caller. But the caller, `printEmp` does not need `avg` to display its results, it only needs a returned value which is then printed by the `printEmp` procedure.

Fix by taking `display` out of the `avg` procedure:

```
(define (avg List)
  (cond ((string=? "std" (car (split List)))
         (/ (examTotals List) 3.0))
        (else 0)))
```